# Add span above html input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've got an `html` input in a `div` that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Barcode" role="barcode">
```

Using only JavaScript I need to add this into the DOM above it:

```
<span class="input-group-btn"><a class="btn btn-default" href="#"><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> Scan</a></span>
```

So the end result is:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn"><a class="btn btn-default" href="#"><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> Scan</a></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Barcode" role="barcode">
</div>
```

I can't use `appendChild` on the div as the `input-group` class is not unique.

This is the JavaScript I've tried with no luck:

```
var barcodeField=document.querySelectorAll('[role=barcode]');
var span=document.createElement('span');
span.class='input-group-btn';
var scanButton=document.createElement('a');
scanButton.class='btn btn-default';
var linkText=document.createTextNode('Scan');
scanButton.href='#';
var i=document.createElement('i');
i.class='fa fa-barcode';
scanButton.appendChild(i);
scanButton.appendChild(linkText);
span.appendChild(scanButton);
barcodeField[0].appendChild(span);
```

For starters it adds it below the input (I know this is due to `appendChild` but `appendParent` doesn't exist and I just wanted to get it working). Also it appears to ignore the classes I've given each element, but the biggest problem is nothing shows up on the page.

The page is also using `Bootstrap` and `JQuery`.

Comment: Give it an ID as well as a class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) as input element can't have descendants, since you want to insert the `span` before the `input` element, you can use [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

```js
var barcodeField = document.querySelector('[role=barcode]');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'input-group-btn';
var scanButton = document.createElement('a');
scanButton.className = 'btn btn-default';
var linkText = document.createTextNode('Scan');
scanButton.href = '#';
var i = document.createElement('i');
i.className = 'fa fa-barcode';
scanButton.appendChild(i);
scanButton.appendChild(linkText);
span.appendChild(scanButton);
barcodeField.parentNode.insertBefore(span, barcodeField);
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Barcode" role="barcode">
</div>
```

---

Also instead of creating the entire html structure using javascript you can

```js
var barcodeField = document.querySelector('[role=barcode]');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'input-group-btn';
span.innerHTML = '<a class="btn btn-default" href="#"><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i>Scan</a>'
barcodeField.parentNode.insertBefore(span, barcodeField);
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Barcode" role="barcode">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - this works. I was using querySelectorAll as the role shows up multiple times on a page and it needs to be added to every element, but I guess I can just wrap up the span creation in a function and loop through the results for barcodeField and run the function for each input?

Comment: @ChrisByatt didn't see you are using jQuery... it is much simpler with that

Answer (score 0):

use `insertBefore` like `$('html to insert').insertBefore('element before which the html has to be inserted')`

```js
$('<span class="input-group-btn"><a class="btn btn-default" href="#"><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> Scan</a></span>').insertBefore('#txtbox')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <input id='txtbox' type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Barcode" role="barcode" />
</div>
```